# ASP.NET MVC - What type of control to use to display read-only text that can be manipulated using jQuery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some read-only data I want to display in a View, but it needs to be manipulated by jQuery in the browser.

I could use Html.DisplayTextFor but then I can't manipulate it (at least, I don't think I can.) Oh, and I also want to be able to style this.

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just output it in a div or span, maybe write an extension method on HtmlHelper to do this (untested):

```
public static string Display(this HtmlHelper html, string value, string cssClass)
{
    TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
    span.InnerHtml = value;
    span.AddCssClass(cssClass);
    return span.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that works, though I'm trying to figure out how to set the ID on the span. Just looking at the implementations of the various helper methods using Reflector, but could use some pointers.

Comment: Ah, found the GenerateId method.